# Magento add canonical link to head section via xml

Tags: xml, magento, layout, head

i'm trying to add my link to head section via my xml file, but nothing happens (magento 1.7.0.2)

```
<action method="addLinkRel"><rel>canonical</rel><href>http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script</href></action>
```

please tell correct way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this, showing complete layout XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>

    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <block type="core/text" name="any.name.here">
                <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script">]]></text></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

The setText lets you do pretty much anything, and will be a safe bet for any third party js or css.

Comment: found another way through a template, maybe someone needs too: $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
$headBlock->addLinkRel('stylesheet', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script');

Comment: Great that it worked for you, could you please also mark this as the correct answer? :)

Comment: There's no need to use CDATA. See my answer below for Magento way of doing this.

Comment: Well, there shouldn't be any need for it - I know. But for Magento version mismatch or other uncertain reasons - your solution does not always work. This does, and setText is a valid Magento function for a reason - not some ugly hack.

Answer (score 4):

`<rel>canonical</rel>` is used for adding a canonical link to the head.

For adding a stylesheet, please use:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addLinkRel">
        <rel>stylesheet</rel>
        <href>http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script</href>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Its worked for me, I was looking to add canonical relation, I just changes it in `<rel>` tag and now working fine,

Answer (score 1):

do you have used `<reference>`?

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addLinkRel">
        <rel>canonical</rel>
        <href>http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script</href>
    </action>
</reference>
```

also check this [link](http://www.adurolabs.com/blog/technical/how-to-add-rel-canonical-in-magento)

Comment: of course: <layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/ring_graving.css</stylesheet></action>
   <action method="addLinkRel"><rel>canonical</rel><href>http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script</href></action>
        </reference>
  </default>
</layout>

Comment: Same code worked for me. I have added my  `<action>` in the `<reference name="head">` tag in my xml file and now its working. I was missing `<href>` tag after `<rel>` to give link.

Answer (score 0):

In my code I usually insert it as a block. See below the google_font_material_icons one:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default translate="label" module="page">
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/style.css</stylesheet><params>media=screen,projection"</params></action>

                <block type="core/text" name="google_font_material_icons">
                    <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">]]></text></action>
                </block>

            </block>
```

....

I hope it helps.